# indexOf cannot be resolved to a type when called on an array

Tags: java, arrays

The `nums.indexOf`  keeps getting an error that states

> indexOf cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Am I supposed to import something? I have already imported `java.util.*`;

```
public static int search(int[] nums)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What value do you want?");
    int value = keyboard.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if(nums.indexOf[i] == value)
            return value;
        else 
            return "Value is not in the list";
    }
}
```

Comment: nums is an int array you can directly do nums[i]==value

Comment: nums.indexOf[i] you typed [] instead of ()

Answer (score 8):

An array does not have a method 'indexOf'.

Use it like this:

```
if(nums[i] == value)
```

Sidenote: use braces (`{}`) around your if-else statements. It's not mandatory but it is definitely advised to avoid problems in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays don't have indexOf() method. Also instead of looping on the array you can use

```
Arrays.asList(nums).contains(i);
```

Comment: For the primitive array `int[]`, `Arrays.asList()` returns `List<int[])`. So it is not usable for an existing **primitive** array. More over `Arrays.asList(nums).contains(i)` silently fails. Use Guava [`Ints.contains(int[] arr, int target)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#contains%28int[],%20int%29) or Apache Commons [`ArrayUtils.contains(int[] arr, int valueToFind)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#contains%28int[],%20int%29) instead